# Как работать с ресурсами в C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, resources, copy

В общем, я добавил папку(с файлами) с названием csharp в папку ресурсов в Windows Forms нужно, чтобы программа по нажатию на кнопку эту папку с файлами копировала допустим в  C:\Users\1\Desktop\papkadlyaResursa

Если у кого-то есть ссылка на хорошие статьи/уроки по работе, тоже буду очень благодарен